# FluentValidation MustAsync child loses parent property value

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

In the parent validator, we have multiple child validations. Declared like this

```
            RuleFor(x => x.Country)
            .Cascade(CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage(ValidationErrorMessageCodes.CountryRequired)
            .SetValidator(new CountryValidator(countryService)).WithMessage(ValidationErrorMessageCodes.CountryDoesNotExist);
```

In the CountryValidator we set this

```
            RuleFor(c => c)
            .MustAsync(async candidateCountryCode =>
                (await countryService.GetAll())
                .Any(x => string.Equals(x.Code, candidateCountryCode, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)))
            .WithMessage(ValidationErrorMessageCodes.CountryDoesNotExist);
```

This all worked fine when we used to use Validate and Must, but now we are using ValidateAsync and MustAsync in order to satisfy calls deeper in the Api all using async Tasks.

Since changing it this way we get the following error message

> Property name could not be automatically determined for expression c => c. Please specify either a custom property name by calling 'WithName'.

If I add .WithName("Country") to the child Validator, then the parameterName returned is "Country.Country" where it used to be just "Country".

Both inherit from AbstractValidator the parent having a RequestModel and the child just being .

What can I do to just get back to the "Country" error ?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to the latest version of FluentValidation solved this problem